# Table vue just filter the current page of the pagination

Tags: javascript, html, search, vue.js, html-table

I have this table with vue js. All work well but the search field just can filter the data of the current page, I want to filter considering all pages of the pagination.

The table is described in the template and below of the table has the pagination. When I click in the button next it show the next page and when click in previous it back page to previous.

I use axios to push data of the the server;

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            Buscar:
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-11">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite algo.." v-model="search">
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center">ID</th>
                <th class="text-center">Transaction</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="order in filteredOrders">

                <td class="text-center">{{ order.id }}</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    {{ order.transaction_name }} of the {{ order.segment_name }}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="row pull-right">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12  m-t-25">
            <ul class="pagination pagination_padding_general_components">
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a href="javascript:void" v-on:click="fetchPaginateOrders(pagination.prev_page_url)" :disabled="!pagination.prev_page_url">Anterior</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item">
                    <a href="#">Pagina {{pagination.current_page}} de {{pagination.last_page}}</a>
                </li>
                <li class="page-item active">
                    <a href="javascript:void" v-on:click="fetchPaginateOrders(pagination.next_page_url)" :disabled="!pagination.prev_page_url">Proxima</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<script>
window.axios = require('axios');
var axios = require('axios');
    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                orders:[],
            search:'',
            pagination:[],
            url: "/admin/orders"
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.fetchOrders();
        },
        methods:{
            fetchOrders:function(){
                let $this = this
            axios
            .get(this.url)
            .then(response => {
                    this.orders = response.data.ordersPaginate.data;
                        this.makePagination(response.data.ordersPaginate.meta.pagination);

                });
            },
            makePagination:function(data){
                let pagination = {
                    current_page: data.current_page,
                    last_page: data.total_pages,
                    next_page_url: data.links.next,
                    prev_page_url: data.links.previous
                }
                this.pagination = pagination;
            },
            fetchPaginateOrders(url){
                this.url = url;
                this.fetchOrders();
            },
        },
        computed:
        {
            let result;

            filteredOrders(){
                result = this.orders.filter(order=>{
                return                  order.transaction_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1 ||
                order.segment_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.search.toLowerCase()) > -1 
            });

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Server side is in laravel and use `Model::orderBy('id','des')->paginate(10)` to get the data

Comment: I suspect you don't have the whole data on client side. You can send filter conditions to server side and to obtain filtered data then use Vue to display it, or download whole dataset (if not too large) and filter on the client side using Vue

Comment: yes, I did in this way already, i get the data in pagination way and all data, so when the this.search.length > 0 it search in all data and not in the pagination, but I got in doubt about good practices. I suppose exists other ways